# I created new angular project and install boots trap and follow error is comming SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am newto the angular and I recently facing this problem my packege.json is followed,as I am using boootstrap 14.0.0. and Angular CLI: 15.0.4 I have attached picture that I am facing

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
enter code here

Comment: Consult the docs for bootstrap. You are probably missing an import in your styles.css. You're question is also very poorly formatted and you never provided what version of bootstrap or Angular and how you are actually setting it up. Quick way to get down-voted

Comment: Question is formated now

Comment: Did you install it with the cli? If not follow this guide to setup for manual install https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: I did everthig I could still same

Comment: I would suggest posting more code here. Perhaps all the steps you took from the guide

Comment: just create angular and install bootstrap, then add necessary imports .json file